# "dpkg status database is locked by another process" while trying to use dpkg along Synaptic

Tags: dpkg, synaptic

I was installing Dropbox when, for some reason, the process got stuck. Synaptic (and apt-get) stopped working after that. I tried some hacks I found on the net and ended up deleting

```
/var/lib/dpkg/lock    .
```

This only worsened my troubles. Running

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

gives me the error -

```
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
```

When opening synaptic:

```
E: Could not open file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you can't use at the same time Synaptic and package-related commands (such as `apt-get` or `dpkg`).

Normally, a simple `sudo apt-get update` should generate a new `pkgcache.bin`, since you seem to have deleted it as well. Can't test it right now, however...

Comment: i had to do this to run apt-get update:  ` rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`